# Blend mode equations including factor/influence

Tags: blend-modes

I have been looking for the equations used for all the blend modes.

In the [Blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Color#Mix_Node)
there are descriptions, but no equations.

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes) there are equations, but there are more than one possible equation for few blend modes (ie soft light).
I don't know which equation blender uses.

I also read [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/blend-modes/info), however the Influence/factor not available on the equations.

It would be much appreciated if the list of equations used in blend modes with factor/influence is made available. Please point me to the right direction if it already exists. Many thanks.

Comment: They might not all be simple *formulas*. The full *algorithm* definitions are [here](http://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/compositor/operations/COM_MixOperation.cpp) (C++).

Comment: Could you request specific blend modes for which you would like equations?

Comment: I'm looking for all the algorithms for blend modes. From the link you provide, I have tackled the non **RGB to HSV to RGB** ones. Now I need equations for these: _HUE, SAT, VALUE, LINEAR, SOFT, COLOR_ blend modes.